# Evaluating differences in Risk Ratio

Tags: confidence-interval, poisson-regression, relative-risk

If I have two risk ratios (calculated from Poisson regression) and 95% confidence intervals for each ratio, can I make the claim that the risk ratios are significantly different if there is no overlap between the confidence intervals?

Moreover, if I can make that claim, is there a citation that proves that that is a legitimate claim to make?

Comment: I don't get what you mean by "two risk ratios". In Poisson regression, we model the expected value of counts on the basis of features.

Comment: Comparing two confidence intervals based on the visual overlap is never legitimate in any circumstance.